# ServerSocket only works on Eclipse - not when embedded to HTML

Tags: java, html, eclipse, server, serversocket

I have created a program that simply has a server which connects the port (6789) and a client when connects to this same port. However, my issue begins with having the server start and connect to port 6789.

The interesting thing is that my server works perfectly in Eclipse, however when it is embedded in HTML, it does not work although the GUI and other functionalities work. The following code is for starting up my server. I have not included the ClientThread or ServerGUI class since my main issue is getting the server to connect to the port anyways.

Is there another port I should be using instead of 6789 when on HTML?

Thank you!

```
public class Server {

    private ServerGUI sg;
    private int port;
    // the boolean that will be turned of to stop the server
    private boolean keepGoing;
    HashSet<String> retailers;
    HashSet<String> retailers_company;
    ArrayList<HashSet<String>> al;

    public Server(int port, ServerGUI sg) {
        this.sg = sg;
        this.port = port;       
    }

    public void start() {
        keepGoing = true;
        try 
        {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            display("Server started on Port: " + port);
            while(keepGoing) 
            {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                if(!keepGoing)
                    break;
                ClientThread t = new ClientThread(socket);
                t.start();
            }
            try {
                serverSocket.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                display("Exception closing the server and clients: " + e);
            }
        }
        // something went bad
        catch (IOException e) {
            display("Exception on new ServerSocket: " + e + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "embedded in HTML"?

Comment: As in the ServerGUI extends JApplet and I have an HTML site running it

Comment: Wow, people still write applets? ;). I'm not certain enough to make it an answer, but I think the applet containers usually forbid unsigned applets from creating server sockets.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that! Thanks for the heads up. Have any idea how I can run my Java program on HTML without using an applet? Or how I could modify my applet?

Comment: You should get an exception that explains what had failed and why. You should probably have included the exception message in your question instead of just saying "does not work".

Comment: Sign the applet. That's all I can think of. You're trying to do something that browser implementors have tried hard to make difficult because of security.

Comment: Thats another issue. None of the exceptions have been caught! So I don't receive any message on what went wrong. This could also mean it is an error rather than an exception. But this did not get displayed on my GUI

Comment: thanks for all the help btw